# install4j: Change label color

Tags: java, bash, install4j

I have three `Run executable or batch file` actions that invokes my launch scripts, tails into the log files respectively, and verifies that each service has started entirely. I would have used the native launch action in install4j but these services need to start in order - synchronously - and take up to 30 seconds per service.

After each action, I have a `Run script` action that verifies the return code and determines whether the rest of the scripts should execute as well. On the form itself, it shows the installed components and I would like to add an icon and change the color of each label after it successfully launches.

If this has confused you, please see the screen shot below to get a better under standing.

[image: screen shot install4j]

And as always, thanks for your support.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is how to get the form environment of a screen from a "Run script" action. A screen that can contain form components is an instance of `com.install4j.api.screens.FormPanelContainer` and that class provides access to the `com.install4j.api.formcomponents.FormEnvironment`.

In a "Run script" action, you can do this:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Color;

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        FormEnvironment formEnvironment = 
            ((FormPanelContainer)context.getScreenById("screenId")).getFormEnvironment();
        JComponent label = (JComponent)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("componentId").
             getConfigurationObject();
        label.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
    }
});
return true;
```

with the appropriate values for "screenId" and "componentId".

for a more reusable solution add

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Color;

public static void changeColor(final String screenId, final String componentId, 
                               final Color color, final Context context) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FormEnvironment formEnvironment = 
               ((FormPanelContainer)context.getScreenById(screenId)).getFormEnvironment();
            JComponent label = (JComponent)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById(componentId).
                getConfigurationObject();
            label.setForeground(color);
        }
    });
}
```

to the static code on the "Installer->Custom Code & resources" step (install4j 6+) and call

```
changeColor("screenId", "componentId", java.awt.Color.GREEN, context);
```

in your "Run script" actions.

---

**For setting an icon**, you have to define the "Icon" property on one label component and use the "Initialization script" property to save it in the context and remove it from the label:

```
context.setVariable("checkIcon", configurationObject.getIcon());
configurationObject.setIcon(null);
```

Then after the call to `label.setForeground();` in the above code snippets, you can call

```
    label.setIcon((Icon)context.getVariable("checkIcon"));
```

Comment: Ingo, this worked perfectly! I hope this isn't too much of a stretch but is it possible to change the icon as well? I have a loading icon next to each service and would like to change that to a check mark if possible! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I've tried out the icon implementation and realized that I'll have 3 different states the service will be in: Starting (loading icon), started (checkmark icon) or failed (X icon). Does the visibility script prevent the initialization script for executing? Sometimes not all 3 services will be set thus some icons will not be present. I'm guessing I'll have to create 3 blank labels that contain the initialization script?

Comment: Yes, you will have to use 3 dummy labels. The initialization script will always run, even if the visibility script returns false.

Comment: Gotcha. It is telling me that `setIcon` is not a valid component when I append it after the setForeground.

Comment: The code is exactly what you have above. I put the `label.setIcon((Icon)context.getVariable("checkIcon"))` directly below the line that sets the foreground and it is telling me setIcon is not a valid component.

Comment: Also, going through the list of available components for JComponent (within the custom code), setIcon is obviously not present. Perhaps setIcon is not a public member of JComponent?

Comment: Maybe the icon is null? I suggest you send me your .install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com so I can have a look at it.